# perl fork vs. thread for shared data structures

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, fork, hash-of-hashes

I am writing a script where I need to share data structures among multiple processes. Currently I am forking, which worked great when I only needed to share simple variables (i.e. $var, @arr, %hash). However more recently I've been trying to share more complex variables, such as a hash of hashes, and I've been running into a lot of trouble. I've tried using [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/~bsugars/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm), [DBM::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/DBM-Deep-2.0008/lib/DBM/Deep.pod), and [forks::shared](http://search.cpan.org/~rybskej/forks-0.34/lib/forks/shared.pm), but they all seem to have issues sharing more complex data structures, like a hash of hashes. What I'm wondering is for a situation like mine, would it be better to use forks or threads? I like the fork syntax because it seems easy to use, but if I'm jumping through a lot of unnecessary hoops when thread would be a lot simpler, I'd definitely like to switch.

**UPDATE**

Share means the separate processes need to both read and write to the data structures.

I am running Perl 5.8 on Centos5.5

Comment: Does "share" mean multiple threads/processes all _updating_ the same structures or just reading from?

Comment: Sorry, "share" means updating and reading.

Comment: You need to provide more context, such as OS and Perl version. Perl provides a poor emulation of posix processes on Win(32|64) platforms and it's not clear which OS you are targeting.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use threads on a POSIX platform. The threads implementation on a POSIX OS clones the whole Perl interpreter providing a poor implementation of processes. You are far better of with traditional IPC.

Comment: @chansen, so using DBM::Deep and forking would be a better solution than threading?

Comment: @srchulo, yes! There might be better modules on CPAN that serves your purpose depending on the number of nodes.

Comment: "You are far better of with traditional IPC." (limited interaction through channels) ...even when using threads.

Comment: I made a comment based on his. I made the same comment in my answer. You are usually far better off with a design that limits interaction to communication channels, regardless of whether you use threads or processes.

Answer (score 2):

You provided absolutely no information about your sharing patterns, so I'll assumes you're using a worker model (which is what you really should be using), which means the data is shared via a message queue.

If so, the answer is "it doesn't matter". Use you choice of `use forks;` or `use threads;`, and use [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread%3a%3aQueue%3a%3aAny) as your inter-task communicate channel.

Comment: But Thread::Queue::Any requires you to be adding variables to a queue, what if I just wanted any of the threads to be able to access it without having to add it to a queue? Like it was just a regular hash.

Comment: Like I said, you did not provide any usage patterns.